# Broadcast address based on IP and subnet mask with mysql

Tags: mysql, subnet

I have the following two columns:

```
SELECT  b.ip_address AS IP ,b.mask AS MASK FROM interfaces b WHERE b.ip_address = 167804290;
+-----------+------------+
| IP        | MASK       |
+-----------+------------+
| 167804290 | 4294967168 | 
+-----------+------------+
```

Where is an actual IP address an its subnet mask

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(b.ip_address) AS IP,INET_NTOA(b.mask) AS MASK FROM interfaces b WHERE b.ip_address = 167804290;

+--------------+-----------------+
| IP           | MASK            |
+--------------+-----------------+
| 10.0.125.130 | 255.255.255.128 | 
+--------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am trying to find a way with mysql to grab the actual broadcast range which in this case is `10.0.125.255` or `167804415`, but I can't see to find it. 
closest I gotten is

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(b.ip_address+(POWER(2,32)- b.mask - 1)) FROM interfaces b WHERE b.ip_address = 167804290; 
+---------------------------------------------------+
| INET_NTOA(b.ip_address+(POWER(2,32)- b.mask - 1)) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 10.0.126.1                                        | 
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Only problem with that, is that this is assuming the column `ip_address` is the start of the subnet `10.0.125.128`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The broadcast address is the complement of the subnet mask, OR'ed with the IP address.

```
SELECT INET_NTOA( ~b.mask & 0xffffffff | b.ip_address) 
FROM interfaces b 
WHERE b.ip_address = 167804290;
```

(You have to mask with "`& 0xffffffff`" because in MySQL, the bitwise complement operator returns a 64-bit value.)